# Trying to sort by date in a grouped dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to produce a dataframe that splits by day (which is the day date of the month) but then orders them by the date.  At the moment the code below splits them into dates e.g. 1 - 11, 2 - 11 but the 30 -10 and 31-10 come after all my November dates.

```
ResultSet2 = ResultProxy2.fetchall()
    
df2 = pd.DataFrame(ResultSet2)
    
resultsrecovery = [group[1] for group in df2.groupby(["day"])]
```

The current code output :

I basically want the grouped dataframe for the 30-10 and 31st of October to come before all the ones in November

[image: illustration]

Comment: have you looked into the method `.sort_values`? it will only work if your dataframe has proper dates though, not strings.

Comment: Yeah, I just get an error : NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupby' when I then try to groupby after using the sort_values

Comment: add your dataframe structure.

Comment: convert your date column in datetime and then use the sort_value method. Used the code below and check if this work  df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

df = df.sort_values(by="date")